# ASUS x550c Not Starting After Enabling XHCI Preboot

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I wanted to boot an Ubuntu pendrive on my ASUS x550c laptop. When I pressed `Esc` during bootup, the boot menu didn't contain a USB entry. So, I went into BIOS settings, and set xHCI Preboot to "Enabled". After this the laptop naturally restarted, but nothing came on screen. No POST, no splash screen. Pressing anything yields to results. The LEDs are on, the fans are spinning, but the screen remains black, and no other lights are flashing. I unplugged all the USB devices, which were the Ubuntu stick (58 GB), and the Bluetooth receiver for a wireless mouse. No changes.

I'm pretty sure that this is not supposed to happen. Please, can anyone give me a clue as to how I may be able to get it going again? I really need it..

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a faulty motherboard. If you have these symptoms, better take it to a technician to change the mobo.